# Amazon AppStream 2.0: Delete user using Aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-appstream

I have a IAM user who has the privilege of

```
+AmazonS3FullAccess
+AdministratorAccess
+IAMUserChangePassword
+AmazonAppStreamFullAccess
```

I have two user in Appstream2

```
John Doe
Alec Stain
```

For Deleting those while I try in command line

```
aws appstream delete-user --user-name [\p{L}\h]+ --authentication-type SAML
```

it returns,

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DeleteUser operation:
```

same thing happens for regex part if I alter with [\p{L}]+ or [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+

Why is this AccessDeniedException and How can I delete appstream2 users anyway?

[if you wonder my credentials might be wrong, the following comman works perfectly

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket test-bucket-989000007 --region us-east-1
```

response:

```
{
    "Location": "/test-bucket-989000007"
}
```

]

Answer (score 3):

I saw that there are no clear answers to this topic anywhere.

Here is an example I used and it worked.

`aws appstream delete-user --user-name user-email --authentication-type USERPOOL`

Answer (score 1):

`--user-name` parameter must be an email address of the user. I think that you can not use regular expression in that parameter. The documentation for the `appstream delete-user` can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteUser.html).

Comment: It's been a long time. The next day I asked for help from aws support  and they resolved the issue. I can't check your suggestion whether it works or not as by now I have no appstream active, I really appreciate your answer and expect it works.

Answer (score 1):

For user in USER Pool you must be use this:

```
aws appstream delete-user --user-name user[email]@domain.tdl --authentication-type USERPOOL
```

And for USER with AD or SAML use this:

```
aws appstream delete-user user[domain]@domain.tdl [\p{L}\h]+ --authentication-type SAML
```